# I'm trying to figure out the right argument for my lapply statment

Tags: r, dataframe, syntax

I have a function that has two parameters. The column name and the data frame.

```
get_col_mean <- function(col_name, data_frame) {
result_for_mean <- mean(life_exp[ ,col_name], na.rm = TRUE)
return(result_for_mean)
}
```

Now I'm making a list excluding the first column of this dataframe here is the code:

```
col_means <- lapply(life_exp$col_name,get_col_mean,life_exp)
```

I know the issue is somewhere in my argument. the main goal of col_means is to have a list of mean averages from all the columns excluding the first column that is a string. Here is a sample of the data set. Any help would be appreciated
[image]

Comment: I know life_exp$col_name doesn't do anything. I've tried this: 
 
life_exp[-1, ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `colMeans` directly without any loop i.e. just remove the first column which is not numeric and apply the `colMeans`

```
colMeans(life_exp[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
life_exp %>%
     summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Based on the OP's code, we need the column names as argument to be looped instead of `life_exp$col_name` (which is not clear whether the OP created a column of column names or not).  If we don't use anonymous/lambda call, then specify the argument of the function to make sure that 'life_exp' is the dataset

```
lapply(names(life_exp)[-1], get_col_mean, data_frame = life_exp)
```

Or using lambda function

```
lapply(names(life_exp)[-1], function(nm) get_col_mean(nm, life_exp))
```

NOTE: The output of `lapply` is always a `list`.  The function returns a numeric `mean` value for each column.  So, if we need a `vector` of `mean`, then either `unlist` the `lapply` output or directly use `sapply`

```
sapply(names(life_exp)[-1], get_col_mean, data_frame = life_exp)
```

Also, this can be automated i.e. if we don't know which are the numeric columns, then create an index first

```
i1 <- sapply(life_exp, is.numeric)
sapply(names(life_exp)[i1], get_col_mean, data_frame = life_exp)
```

Comment: Makes plenty of sense Thank you!